# Networkx: Drawing parallel edges

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

Plot a graph from a dataframe with the code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
           'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
           'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Bruno'],
           'weight_1': [8,9,10,11,12],
           'weight_2':[5,6,7,8,9] })

 G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

 G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
 emp = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]

 G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
 dep = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

 G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['name_dep', 'id_emp', 'weight_1']].values)
 G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'weight_2']].values)
 edge_width = [a[2]['weight']//2 for a in G.edges(data=True)]

 plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

 pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.9)
 nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=dep, node_color='#bfbf7f', node_shape="h", node_size=300, with_labels = True)
 nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=emp, node_color='red', node_size=300, with_labels = True)
 nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, width=edge_width, alpha=0.2)

 plt.axis('off')
 plt.show()
```

output:

[image]

In the example shown, each vertex has an input edge and an output edge, which would configure parallel edges between two vertices. However the networkx plots the graph with the edges overlapping each other, giving the impression that between two vertices there is only one edge. So, how can I configure the networkx so that the output is similar to the image below?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use [graphviz](https://graphviz.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) python library.

```
sudo apt-get install graphviz
pip install graphviz
```

I tried on Jupyter notebook (which is natively supported)

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
           'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
           'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Bruno'],
           'weight_1': [8,9,10,11,12],
           'weight_2':[5,6,7,8,9] })

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
emp = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]

G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
dep = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['name_dep', 'id_emp', 'weight_1']].values)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'weight_2']].values)
edge_width = [a[2]['weight']//2 for a in G.edges(data=True)]

########################################################################
###########################CODE TO ADD##################################
########################################################################
import graphviz

d = graphviz.Digraph()

for n in dep:
    d.node(str(n), color="#bfbf7f")

for n in emp:
    d.node(str(n), color="red")

for e in G.edges:
    d.edge(str(e[0]), str(e[1]))

d.attr(size='8')

# To display the graph on Jupyter
d
```

Displays :

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Networkx can't draw parallel edges correctly. If you want to draw them, you need to create a DOT file using Graphviz (Agraph) with [write_dot](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_agraph.write_dot.html#networkx-drawing-nx-agraph-write-dot) function and convert it to an image later:

`nx.nx_agraph.write_dot(G, path_to_store_dot_file)`

Comment: i always do this to visualise them.

Answer (score 2):

I found that @AMangipinto's answer didn't work (using nx version 2.2): another way is to draw the edges in afterwards with matplotlib directly:

```
    import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
           'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
           'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Bruno'],
           'weight_1': [8,9,10,11,12],
           'weight_2':[5,6,7,8,9] })

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
emp = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]
G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
dep = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['name_dep', 'id_emp', 'weight_1']].values)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'weight_2']].values)
edge_width = [a[2]['weight']//2 for a in G.edges(data=True)]

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.9)


nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=dep, node_color='#bfbf7f', node_shape="h", node_size=300, with_labels = True)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, nodelist=emp, node_color='red', node_size=300, with_labels = True)
ax = plt.gca()
for edge in G.edges:
    ax.annotate("",
                xy=pos[edge[0]], xycoords='data',
                xytext=pos[edge[1]], textcoords='data',
                arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->", color="0.5",
                                shrinkA=5, shrinkB=5,
                                patchA=None, patchB=None,
                                connectionstyle="arc3,rad=-0.3",
                                ),
                )

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found also a quicker solution to this problem. This is adding the [connectionstyle](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.ConnectionStyle.html) keyword to nx.draw_networkx_nodes.

So in particular for your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx

df = pd.DataFrame({'id_emp' : [13524791000109, 12053850000137, 4707821000113, 4707821000114, 1],
           'name_emp': ['Cristiano', 'Gaúcho', 'Fenômeno','Angelin', 'Souza'],
           'name_dep': ['Ronaldo','Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Ronaldo', 'Bruno'],
           'weight_1': [8,9,10,11,12],
           'weight_2':[5,6,7,8,9] })

G = nx.MultiDiGraph()

G.add_nodes_from(df['id_emp'], bipartite = 0)
emp = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 0]
G.add_nodes_from(df['name_dep'], bipartite = 1)
dep = [v for v in G.nodes if G.nodes[v]['bipartite'] == 1]

G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['name_dep', 'id_emp', 'weight_1']].values)
G.add_weighted_edges_from(df[['id_emp', 'name_dep', 'weight_2']].values)
edge_width = [a[2]['weight']//2 for a in G.edges(data=True)]

plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.9)

# Here there is the addition:

nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.3', nodelist=dep, node_color='#bfbf7f', node_shape="h", node_size=300, with_labels = True)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.3', nodelist=emp, node_color='red', node_size=300, with_labels = True)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(G, pos, connectionstyle='arc3, rad = 0.3', width=edge_width, alpha=0.2)

plt.axis('off')
plt.show()
```

And here you see a picture of how it looks like:

[image: Parallel edges example]