# How to show graph with matrix in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matrix, sna

I want to show graph with matrix below.
I've saved this matrix in excel file to import that to gephi application but it doesn't work .
How can I show it?

```
0 0 0 1 0 0
0 0 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0 0 
1 0 1 0 1 2
0 0 0 1 0 1
0 0 0 2 1 0
```

Comment: Would you like to show an Adjacency matrix?

Comment: @Glycerine     Yes   , I want to show a Adjacency matrix

Comment: @Glycerine I may ask you to help me

Comment: Does a `2` in your matrix represent double edge weight or two edges?  Do you care if this is shown in the graph?

Comment: @Frodnar It represent two edges

Comment: Ah, networkx doesn't have good native support for visualizing multiple parallel edges as evidenced by multiple Stack Overflow threads ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56543559/networkx-drawing-parallel-edges) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785849/drawing-multiple-edges-between-two-nodes-with-networkx), for example). Those linked threads provide several options for workarounds / other packages to consider.

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx


matrix = np.array([ [0,0,0,1,0,0]
                   ,[0,0,1,0,0,0]
                   ,[0,1,0,1,0,0]
                   ,[1,0,1,0,1,2]
                   ,[0,0,0,1,0,1]
                   ,[0,0,0,2,1,0]])

G = nx.from_numpy_array(matrix)

nx.draw(G, with_labels=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I got this error: "NetworkXError: random_state_index is incorrect"

Comment: Ah yeah, this is a known bug. I believe upgrading `decorator` module will fix it.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66920533/networkx-shows-random-state-index-is-incorrect/66921155#66921155).

Comment: I have seen this link before but I do not know where to change the version?

Comment: How do you install python packages like `networkx`?  `conda` and `pip` are the most common methods from the command line.  So probably one of: `pip install decorator --upgrade` or `conda update decorator`

Comment: I tried different versions for this package but unfortunately it still does not work

Comment: Hmmm.   It still sounds like a package conflict / installation issue.  I would try installing in a fresh install in a clean virtual environment if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I took some extra days to research this one and I found `matrix-47`, of which allows printing and managing these matrix formats:

https://github.com/AnonymouX47/matrix

```
>>> from matrix import Matrix
>>> print(Matrix(4, 4))
+―――――――――――――――+
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|―――+―――+―――+―――|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|―――+―――+―――+―――|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
|―――+―――+―――+―――|
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
+―――――――――――――――+

>>> from matrix import *
>>> m = randint_matrix(3, 3, range(-9, 10))
>>> print(m)
+――――――――――――――+
| 9  | -1 | 9  |
|――――+――――+――――|
| 2  | -8 | -1 |
|――――+――――+――――|
| -4 | 0  | 9  |
+――――――――――――――+
```